# Send BS (Backspace) to a TMemo

Tags: delphi-7, vcl, delphi

I would like to send a BackSpace control char to a TMemo like the user would actually press the BackSpace button.

My Memo is readonly and if I click a button it should delete the last char in the memo. 
I would like to do that without using Memo.Text := ... (so no redraw or beginupdate, etc.) 
Is that possible, if yes, how?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: I tried to add #8 but no luck...

Comment: Changing `Text` is your solution. If the Memo is read only, it's going to ignore your attempts to type in it. If you want to delete just the final character then there are windows messages that do that efficiently. That's better than re-populating the entire text. Would you like an explanation of how to do that?

Comment: I know about SendMessage but I don't know what params to use. A sample would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sending a key press to a read only memo won't work. The key press will be ignored because the memo is read only. To delete the final character of a memo in an efficient way, that is without replacing the entire contents, you can use [`EM_SETSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661.aspx) and [`EM_REPLACESEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633.aspx).

```
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := Memo1.GetTextLen;
  SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_SETSEL, Len-1, Len);
  SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, LPARAM(PChar('')));
end;
```

Or if you prefer a pure VCL version which wraps up these Windows messages:

```
begin
  Memo1.SelStart := Memo1.GetTextLen-1;
  Memo1.SelLength := 1;
  Memo1.SelText := '';
end;
```

The latter probably sends a few more Windows messages, but is much easier to read. I would prefer the latter option.

One possible problem I can see with this is that it may not do what you want with line breaks. Since a Windows line break is two characters (CR+LF), you would need to delete two characters if the last character in the memo was LF. To handle that you can probably do it like this:

```
begin
  Memo1.SelStart := Memo1.GetTextLen-1;
  Memo1.SelLength := 1;
  if Memo1.SelText=#10 then
  begin
    Memo1.SelStart := Memo1.SelStart-1;
    Memo1.SelLength := 2;
  end;
  Memo1.SelText := '';
end;
```

Comment: looks good thank you. I don't know why but the last char gets stuck and stays in the memo.

Comment: I had an off-by-one error. I think the code's good now. A little final testing underway here....

Comment: Yup, I'm happy with it now. Use the third version which deals with line breaks. Of course it does assume that line breaks are always CR+LF but no matter, you have enough here to make it as robust as you need.

Comment: Sorry for being to the party, but how would you perform a VK_RETURN (ENTER) to a Memo ?

Another question, how come TMemo doesn't respond to WM_KEYUP/DOWN messages ?

Btw, instead of using SendMessage, you can just do Memo1.Perform()